# Make highlight-changes-mode untrack specific changes

Tags: highlighting, overlays

I recently discovered `highlight-changes-mode` and I added it to my proofs-typesetting setup (LaTeX). I usually make some temporary changes to my buffer that I like not to be tracked (highlighted) when `higlight-changes-mode` is active.

Is it possible to do it? If so, how?

**Edit.** As for regexp highlighting in my question [highlight-regexp: what's the variable in which they are stored?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46584/15606) I imagine it can be done by let binding the variable(s) in which overlays are stored. Unfortunately I've not been able to find it.

A MWE of what I'm searching for can be explained by the following example.

Let's say I'm working on a LaTeX project in the proofreading stage. At a certain point I want to highlight a word/regexp in the PDF output. I can do:

```
(save-excursion
  ;; "WORD" --> "{\color{red} WORD}"
  (perform-replace "WORD" 
                   "{\\color{red} WORD}" 
                   nil nil nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (save-buffer)

  ;; pdflatex the buffer-file
  (tex-file)

  (perform-replace "{\\color{red} WORD}" 
                   "WORD" 
                   nil nil nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (save-buffer)
  )
```

In this case `highlight-changes-mode` will track all my temporary changes. My purpose is to create a wrapper form this kind of operation that makes them not be tracked by `highlight-changes-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

`highlight-changes-remove-highlight` might be handy for this. The best way to find out about it is to read the source file for the highlight-changes code.