# highlight-regexp: what's the variable in which they are stored?

Tags: font-lock, highlighting, hi-lock

I need to write a macro, `with-temp-highlight-regexps`, that evaluates `BODY` and than restores the previous highlighted regexps (created with the `highlight-regexp` function). I thought I could do it by let-binding the variable in which this kind of highlights are stored. I read the `hi-lock.el` file but I'm not so skilled to find the info I need.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT.** I tried this approach following [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils)' suggestion:

```
(defun my-temp-highlights () 
   (interactive)

   (highlight-regexp "STRING 1")

   (let ((hi-lock-interactive-patterns hi-lock-interactive-patterns))
     (highlight-regexp "STRING 2")

     (read-string "\"RETURN\" TO QUIT"))
   )
```

Running this function should keep `STRING 1` highlighted but the `STRING 2` highlighting should turn off, keeping the highlight only until `RETURN`. The strange behaviour (for me) of this function is that the `STRING 2` highlight is non turned off when I run `hi-lock-mode`.

(I know I coud use `unhilight-regexp` but it is not what I'm searching for.)

**EDIT 2.** I also the following code to understand what happens:

```
(defun my-temp-highlights () 
   (interactive)

   (highlight-regexp "STRING 1")
   (princ hi-lock-interactive-patterns)
   (sit-for 5)

   (let ((BACKUP_VAR hi-lock-interactive-patterns))
     (highlight-regexp "STRING 2")
     (princ hi-lock-interactive-patterns)
     (sit-for 5)
     (read-string "ENTER TO QUIT")
     (setq hi-lock-interactive-patterns BACKUP_VAR))

   (princ hi-lock-interactive-patterns)
   (sit-for 5)

     )
```

But I'm not able to figure out why the second regexp (`STRING 2`) keeps to be highlighted when the `hi-lock-interactive-patterns` value is restored. (And why hi-lock-mode turn off does NOT effect it's higlighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `hi-lock-interactive-patterns`

---

*Following the question edit...*

> The strange behaviour (for me) of this function is that the STRING 2 highlight is non turned off

Ultimately `hi-lock` is using the `font-lock` machinery, and so the patterns get added to (but not removed from) `font-lock-keywords` with the way your code was working.  Perhaps in your use-case you want to be using that more directly.

> I know I coud use unhilight-regexp but it is not what I'm searching for.

Given that you are calling `read-string` -- at which point other code (e.g. process filters) may be running -- it may be preferable to use that approach.

You could adapt your function like so:

```
(defun my-temp-highlights () 
  (interactive)

  (highlight-regexp "STRING 1")

  (let ((pattern "STRING 2"))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (highlight-regexp pattern)
          (read-string "\"RETURN\" TO QUIT"))
      (unhighlight-regexp pattern))))
```

Comment: Please take a look at the editing of my question, maybe you could help me.

Comment: Ok, the `font-lock-keywords` hint helped to realize my purpose. Thanks. (Take a look at my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

A way to think about figuring that out is to wonder what code in hi-lock needs to know what has been highlighted. An obvious place is in the code for unhighlighting, since it prompts for a choice of regexps that have already been highlighted. If you look at the function, you can probably chase it down from there.

Answer (score 0):

Following [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils)' hints I wrote this macro that fits my purpose:

```
(defmacro with-temp-highlights (&rest body)      
  `(unwind-protect
       (let ((font-lock-keywords font-lock-keywords)
             (hi-lock-interactive-patterns hi-lock-interactive-patterns))
     ,@body
     )

     ;; *DUMMY HIGHLIGHT* 
     ;; I need it to reapply the highlights stored in the
     ;; `font-lock-keywords` and `hi-lock-interactive-patterns`
     ;; variables
     (highlight-regexp "MY DUMMY REGEXP")
     (unhighlight-regexp "MY DUMMY REGEXP")
     ))
```

It makes temporary the regexp highlighs in `BODY` keeping all the preexisting highlights.

You can test it evaluating:

```
(highlight-regexp "Chicchirichì")

(with-temp-highlights
 (highlight-regexp "Coccodè")
 (sit-for 3))
```

My only perplexity is about the DUMMY HIGHLIGHT stuff, but I didn't found and alternative way to reset/reload the 2 let-binded variables.